# NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.ForeignKey

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa

When I'm trying to run a test (in fact it's empty and I'm using it to control building of my test :)) I'm getting error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindManyToOne(AnnotationBinder.java:2898)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1742)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:906)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:733)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:245)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:222)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:265)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:848)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:876)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:135)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:319)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
```

My POM.xml looks like that:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>StarterKit</groupId>
   <artifactId>Gielda</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

   <properties>
         <java.version>1.8</java.version>
         <spring.framework.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
         <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
         <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
         </dependency>
         <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
         </dependency>
         <!--     http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>1.10.1.RELEASE</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>6.0.2</version>
         </dependency>
         <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.el/el-api -->
         <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
                <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
         </dependency>
         <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.web/javax.el -->
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.6</version>
         </dependency>

         <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
         </dependency>
         <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
         </dependency>
         <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
         </dependency>
         <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-annotations -->
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
         </dependency>
         <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate -->
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
         </dependency>
         <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-commons-annotations -->
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
         </dependency>
         <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.19</version>
         </dependency>
         <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.19</version>
         </dependency>
         <!--     http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jadira.usertype/usertype.core -->
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
                <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0.GA</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jinq</groupId>
                <artifactId>jinq-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
         </dependency>
         <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hsqldb/hsqldb -->
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
                <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.3</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
                <groupId>ma.glasnost.orika</groupId>
                <artifactId>orika-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.5</version>
         </dependency>

   </dependencies>

   <dependencyManagement>
         <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                       <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                       <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                       <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                       <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                       <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                       <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                       <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                       <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                       <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                       <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                       <groupId>junit</groupId>
                       <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                       <version>${junit.version}</version>
                       <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                       <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                       <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
                       <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
         </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>

   <build>
         <plugins>
                <plugin>
                       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                       <configuration>
                             <source>1.8</source>
                             <target>1.8</target>
                       </configuration>
                </plugin>
         </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

and persistence.xml like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="Gielda">
    <class>pl.spring.demo.entity.KursEntity</class>
    <class>pl.spring.demo.entity.SpolkaEntity</class>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I've seen in other topics that it can be caused by version of javax.persistence or hibernate but it seems for me, that I have both: persistence of version 2.1 and Hibernate newer than 4.3. Do you know maybe how I'm still getting this error?

My 2 Entities:

```
package pl.spring.demo.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name="kursy")
@NamedQuery(name="KursEntity.findAll", query="SELECT k FROM KursEntity k")
public class KursEntity implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="id_kursu")
private long idKursu;

private BigDecimal cena;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="data_kursu")
private Date dataKursu;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to SpolkaEntity
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="nazwa_spolki")
private SpolkaEntity spolki;

public KursEntity() {
}

public KursEntity(long idKursu, BigDecimal cena, Date dataKursu, SpolkaEntity spolki) {
    this.idKursu = idKursu;
    this.cena = cena;
    this.dataKursu = dataKursu;
    this.spolki = spolki;
}

public long getIdKursu() {
    return this.idKursu;
}

public void setIdKursu(long idKursu) {
    this.idKursu = idKursu;
}

public BigDecimal getCena() {
    return this.cena;
}

public void setCena(BigDecimal cena) {
    this.cena = cena;
}

public Date getDataKursu() {
    return this.dataKursu;
}

public void setDataKursu(Date dataKursu) {
    this.dataKursu = dataKursu;
}

public SpolkaEntity getSpolki() {
    return this.spolki;
}

public void setSpolki(SpolkaEntity spolki) {
    this.spolki = spolki;
}

}
```

and

```
 package pl.spring.demo.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name="spolki")
@NamedQuery(name="SpolkaEntity.findAll", query="SELECT s FROM SpolkaEntity s")
public class SpolkaEntity implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private String nazwa;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to KursEntity
@OneToMany(mappedBy="spolki")
private List<KursEntity> kursy;

public SpolkaEntity() {
}

public SpolkaEntity(String nazwa, List<KursEntity> kursy) {
    this.nazwa = nazwa;
    this.kursy = kursy;
}

public String getNazwa() {
    return this.nazwa;
}

public void setNazwa(String nazwa) {
    this.nazwa = nazwa;
}

public List<KursEntity> getKursy() {
    return this.kursy;
}

public void setKursy(List<KursEntity> kursy) {
    this.kursy = kursy;
}

public KursEntity addKursy(KursEntity kursy) {
    getKursy().add(kursy);
    kursy.setSpolki(this);

    return kursy;
}

public KursEntity removeKursy(KursEntity kursy) {
    getKursy().remove(kursy);
    kursy.setSpolki(null);

    return kursy;
}

}
```

database-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

   <context:annotation-config />
   <context:component-scan base-package="pl.spring.demo.entity" />

   <jpa:repositories base-package="pl.spring.demo.repository" />

   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

   <bean id="transactionManager"     class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
         <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
   </bean>

   <!--<util:properties     id="hsqldbJpaProps"location="classpath:/test_data_access/hsqldb_jpa.properties" 
         /> -->


   <!--<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL" /> -->

   <bean name="dataSource"
         class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
         <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
         <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gielda" />
         <property name="username" value="root" />
         <property name="password" value="starterkit" />
   </bean>


   <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
              class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
         <property name="packagesToScan" value="pl.spring.demo.entity" />
         <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

         <property name="jpaProperties">
                <props>
                       <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                       <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                       <prop     key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                </props>
         </property>

         <property name="persistenceProvider">
                <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider">        </bean>
         </property>
   </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: I think that there is something missing in your persistence.xml. Where is the rest of the db configuration properties? And why are you establishing dependencies with both MySQL and HSQLDB? Maybe there is a conflict between them that generates that exception. Can you post the entity where you are using @JoinColumn?

Comment: Why do you need the persistence.xml then? Have you tried commenting the hsqldb dependencies in your pom.xml when you use MySQL? Your use of @JoinColumn (and the rest of your mapping) seems correct to me.

Comment: commenting this part doesn't change anything, so I don't need it. What's more that seems to be true that I also don't need persistence.xml. I've commented whole file and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: NoSuchMethodError is very clear ... the method is NOT PRESENT IN THE LOADED CLASS of that name ... so you have a version that is not JPA 2.1 in the CLASSPATH

Comment: more caps, more irony, more -1 votes, more wrong please. I've solved this problem and the solution wasn't in your link, and my JPA was ok in classpath. Cya